# How can I find Tomcat path from windows services, through batch file

Tags: batch-file, tomcat

Thanks for looking into my query.
I have tomcat installed as windows service with the service name as 'Tomcat8'.
I would like to get the tomcat path by querying windows services through batch file.

Could you please suggest how to get Tomcat8 path from windows services.

What I tried?
I tried below approach by using reg query

Command:

```
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat8" /v "ImagePath"
```

Output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat8
ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\tomcat8.exe //RS// Tomcat8
```

But, this command is not giving absolute path. I want get absolute path for tomcat (eg: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15).

Comment: ...but the absolute path is `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\tomcat8.exe`; it's location is `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin`. Could you please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f "delims=/" %%a IN ('reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat8" /v "ImagePath"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims= " %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%b"=="ImagePath" (
    FOR %%m IN ("%%~dpd.") DO ECHO %%~dpm
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Taking the output of the `reg query` command, take the very first token on the line (default) but set `delims` to `/` to remove the trailing waffle that appears to be there (since it's //... then it would be assigned to the second token, had it been specified)

Tokenise the result again, this time using space as a delimiter and select 1st, 2nd and rest-of-the-line to `%%b`..`%%d` respectively. Gate the critical string in `%%b` to ensure only that line is processed; The executable-filename appears in `%%d`. Select the drive and path of this, pop a `.` on the end so the parser sees `bin` as a filename and select the drive&path of the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt response with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reg query` command line does return an absolute path to the Tomcat8 executable. You seem to want to get its grand-parent directory.

At first, we need to capture the output of the `req query` command line, using a `for /F` loop:

```cmd
for /F "skip=1 delims" %%R in ('
    reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat8" /V "ImagePath"
') do set "RVAL=%%R"
```

This skips the header and captures the entire line then:

> ```cmd
> ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\tomcat8.exe //RS// Tomcat8
> ```

The next thing is to remove the leading value name and type separated by four consecutive <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, and the trailing stuff <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `//RS//` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>:

```cmd
set "RVAL=%RVAL:*    =%"
set "RVAL=%RVAL:*    =%"
set "RVAL=%RVAL: //RS// =" & rem "%"
```

Now let us append `\..` as many times we want to go up in the directory hierarchy:

```cmd
set "RVAL=%RVAL%\..\.."
```

Finally, to resolve the path, a `for` loop is the best suitable tool:

```cmd
for %%R in ("%RVAL%") do set "RVAL=%%~fR"
```

This is just a cosmetical thing, because `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\bin\tomcat8.exe\..\..` is functionally equivapent to `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.15`.